# Display the parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, display

I'm trying to display my name through the use of a function parameter, however, i get the error ***Maximum call stack size exceeded*** when runnning my code.
I have to be able to change the displayed name through the parameter.

```
var naam;
function groet(naam){

var naam = groet();
console.log("Hey " + naam);
return naam;
}

groet("Rick");
```

Any help? Cheers!

Comment: Stackoverflow because of infinite recursion.

Comment: `var naam = groet();` <=== Why did you do this?  In other words, what did you expect to happen when you made this call?  Did you realize this is recursive?  And do you understand what recursion means?

Comment: you are making recursive calls every time the groet () function is executed, until the stack of heap calls full.

Comment: Never heard of it, like i said i´m kind of new at this stuff. Now that someone´s explained it to me it seems kind of baffling how i could´ve missed this, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `groet("Rick")` it calls `groet()` which calls `groet()` which calls `groet()` which calls `groet()`...

Use the parameter like this.

```
function groet(naam){
    console.log("Hey " + naam);
}

groet("Rick");
```

Comment: I think you missed that `groet()` calls `groet()` calls `groet()` calls **MAXIMUM SILLY REFERENCES AMOUNT REACHED!**

Comment: Thanks! I´m new to all of this stuff so i appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is recursive (it calls itself). You are missing a key requirement for the recursion to work, the base case. Base cases are conditions under which you don't call the function itself anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP isn't responding to questions it's rather difficult to determine where their confusion lies.  I guess they don't understand [recursion](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html) (a function that calls itself):

```
function groet(naam){
  var naam = groet();//Call to self
  console.log("Hey " + naam);
  return naam;
}
```

This implementation lacks a [recursive termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination).  Recursive algorithms need to have a condition that will eventually stop the method from calling itself.

This algorithm lacks such a condition so we get the exception that basically tells us we called our function an infinite number of times.

The OP gave us this condition:

> I have to be able to change the displayed name through the parameter.

For this, all we need is something like Ben West posted:

```
function groet(naam){
    console.log("Hey " + naam);
    return naam;
}

groet("Rick");
```

Because a variable is by it's very nature...variable.  Recursion is not necessary to solve the problem of having a variable name.  So recursion can be removed.  The OP may need to `return naam`.  If, for example `naam` is a contrived example and in reality they are modifying the value of `naam` in the implementation.  By default JavaScript will return undefined here.